# Creating a string that will splits multiple words into letters

Tags: java

So I am doing an assignment for school were we have to build a hang man game with multiple words to guess, but right now I only have one. I want to know how to get a string of words, such as String[] words = "hello","funny","apple"; and split them up into singular letters, such as "h","e","l","l","o", in saying this I don't want all the letters all jumbled up, but I want them to be assigned to that word.

Comment: There's `.toCharArray()` for creating a character array, or `.split("")` for creating a string array. You may be interested in reading the [documentation for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making an array of char arrays and using .toCharArray() to get the char array from the string.

```
String[] words = {"hello", "funny", "apple"};

// make an array of char arrays
char[][] letters = new char[words.length][];

for (int q = 0; q < letters.length; q++){
    letters[q]=words[q].toCharArray(); // get the char[] of the word
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters[0]));
```

This will return:

```
[h, e, l, l, o]
```